# Limit memory for browser on Fedora

Tags: fedora, cgroups

I would like to limit memory usage for Chromium (/bin/chromium-browser) and Firefox (/bin/firefox) for all users.

Before moving to Fedora I was using cgroups for that. However, I heard that on Fedora cgroups are deprecated. How can I set limit of 1GB RAM without cgroups?

EDIT:
I have tried doing it with cgroups.

/etc/cgconfig.conf

```
group browsers { 
    memory { 
        memory.limit_in_bytes = 1024m;
        memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes = 1024m;
        memory.soft_limit_in_bytes = 1024m; 
    } 
}
```

/etc/cgrules.conf

```
*:/bin/chromium-browser memory browsers
```

but after

```
sudo service cgconfig start
systemctl status cgconfig.service
```

I am receiving

```
● cgconfig.service - Control Group configuration service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/cgconfig.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-06-24 13:41:07 CEST; 29min ago
  Process: 9239 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cgconfigparser -l /etc/cgconfig.conf -s 1664 (code=exited, status=87)
 Main PID: 9239 (code=exited, status=87)

Jun 24 13:41:07 me systemd[1]: Starting Control Group configuration service...
Jun 24 13:41:07 me cgconfigparser[9239]: /usr/sbin/cgconfigparser; error loading /etc/cgconfig.conf: Cgroup, operation not allowed
Jun 24 13:41:07 me systemd[1]: cgconfig.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=87/n/a
Jun 24 13:41:07 me systemd[1]: cgconfig.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 24 13:41:07 me systemd[1]: Failed to start Control Group configuration service.
```

I will be happy with either working cgroups or alternative approach without cgroups.

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/resource_management_guide/chap-introduction_to_control_groups

Comment: That says that `libcgroup` is deprecated, not the entire cgroups subsystem.

Comment: please see my edit

Answer (score 7):

Another approach is to use `systemd-run` and [`MemoryHigh`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html#MemoryHigh=bytes) resource control, like

`systemd-run --user --no-block -p MemoryHigh=1G firefox`

`MemoryHigh` is a feature of CGroup V2 and is not deprecated. [As explained in systemd.resource-control(5) manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html#Unified%20and%20Legacy%20Control%20Group%20Hierarchies) we must let systemd use CGroup V2. To do this, we have to add `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grun` then run `update-grub`. Please note that this resource control is broken and does not work in some versions of systemd, e.g. [v239 (where a workaround is also available)](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/9512).

Answer (score 1):

You could validate syntax of your files interactively:

```
$ sudo cgconfigparser -l /etc/cgconfig.conf -s 640 -t your-uid:your-gid
```

You need to create the cgroup and associate permissions

```
$ sudo cgcreate -a your-uid:your-gid -t your-uid:your-gid -g memory:browsers
```

Then try to start your browser with cgroups active:

```
$ cgexec -g memory:/browsers /bin/chromium-browser
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `timeout` can help you: https://github.com/pshved/timeout

From the github page:

`-t T` - set up CPU+SYS time limit to T seconds

`-m M` - set up virtual memory limit to M kilobytes

So you have to run `timeout -m 1000000 /bin/chromium-browser` for example.

You could replace the application starter/menu entry to run the above command for more convenience.